# Will system restore "restore" a wubi root.disk?

Tags: wubi

I have Windows XP on C:, and installed Wubi Ubuntu 10.10 on D:\ubuntu.

I encountered a power interruption while using XP. When the power got back, I booted into Ubuntu, detected the Windows wasn't properly shutdown, fixed it, and went on to boot Ubuntu just fine.

Then the next day, I wasn't able to boot into ubuntu. Did chkdsk on D: since a folder I was trying to copy files into (when the power went out) got corrupted.

XP is fine, but Ubuntu still won't boot. After trying lots of solutions that didn't work, I just found out that the whole /ubuntu/disks/ folder is gone.

So, before doing system restore, will it restore my root.disk? Thank you.

Comment: Better asked on superuser; but i'm afraid not, system restore only monitors those directories/files required to recover windows into a working state, its not a disk imaging/backup feature

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows XP System Restore monitors only a list of file extensions defined in `%SystemRoot%\system32\Restore\filelist.xml`, and `DISK` is *not* in it.

If you [find a way](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553) to run `explorer /separate` as the "SYSTEM" user, you can browse *C:\System Volume Information* for files of the same size as your `root.disk`, but it's unlikely to be there.