# Recover deleted data with rm -rf (wubi ubuntu 10.10)

Tags: ubuntu, software-rec, data-recovery, wubi

I accidentally deleted /home directory with sudo rm -rf... :(

I tried to restore it with testdisk, but becouse Ubuntu is from Wubi, it cannot list filesystem and dont know another way to do this.

How could i restore my data? It's important.

Please help.

Wubi, Ubuntu 10.10

Comment: if you are using Windows 7 you may try System Restore and recover a system snapshot before the time you deleted the files.

Comment: @Pablo Castellazzi: I believe Windows System restore only covers system files (hence the name) - it will not touch the user's personal files, thus the image file that Wubi uses would probably not be restored.

Comment: @sleske: I was not sure if it would work or not. I understood "User's personal files" as anything in C:\Users. Since wubi files are outside that path i thought it may work. Anyway it does not work. This exact question was asked [here](http://superuser.com/questions/286678/will-system-restore-restore-a-wubi-root-disk).

Answer (score 2):

First of all, *make a backup of your Wubi installation file*. That should be the file `C:\ubuntu\disks\root.disk`. Do *not* try to boot your Wubi installation before doing this, as this may overwrite the data you deleted.

To try and recover the data, boot your computer from a Linux rescue CD (or copy the Wubi file to a Linux computer, or to a removable media).

Then use an undelete utility to try and save your data. For possible approaches, see e.g. [How to recover a removed file under Linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/150027/how-to-recover-a-removed-file-under-linux)

If an undelete utility refuses to read a filesystem from a file, you can create a loopback device (as root):

```
# losetup /dev/loop0 /my/wubi/file
```

Afterwards, the file will be accessible as a device under `/dev/loop0`, where you can use tools on it (or even mount it, though that will not help you).

To remove the loopback device when you're done:

```
# losetup -d /dev/loop0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try ext3grep ,if its ext4FS then try extundelete. If both  tools doesn't help,may be you can try file carving  tools like foremost,sleuth-kit,scapel or extcarve

Comment: Thanks all, i found the solution here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/52693/recover-deleted-data-with-rm-rf